# Cannot find temporary tables that are created in Temp folder of System Database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

I created a temporary table using the following syntax.

```
create table #FillDataGrid(
    Serial_No int identity(1,1),
    ItemCode varchar(50),
    ItemName varchar(50),
    ItemDesc varchar(50),
    UOM varchar(20),
    Quantity int,
    Rate float,
    Amount float
)
```

But after the query successfully executed i couldn't find that database in any of the folder. Actually it has to exist in `Temp` folder of `System Database`. Tried this also:

```
select * from tempdb.sys.objects
```

Comment: "it has to exist in Temp folder of System Database" - Why?

Comment: select * from #FillDataGrid??

Comment: Because whatever the temporary tables which exists all will be residing in Temp foder right ??

Comment: select * from #FillDataGrid resulting in an error **Invalid object name '#FillDataGrid'**

Comment: @SujithHS It's not "a Temp folder". It's the `tempdb` system database.

Comment: @AlbertoSolano ya thats exactly true.But couldn't find my table there.

Comment: @SujithHS The query used to create the table is correct. Check your connection string (if you're executing the query locally, but you expect the result in another instance), and if there's a `drop table #FillDataGrid` statement executed after the creation of temporary table.

Comment: Are you closing your connection after creating the table? As temp tables are dropped when they go out of scope, closing your connection will cause it to be removed.

Comment: @AlbertoSolano there is no drop table statement after the creation of table and the connection string is absolutely perfect !! But still...:-(

Comment: @steoleary Yup, I am closing the connection properly.

Comment: Should I use temporary variable for that Declare @Temp_name ? Do you think is that better than this one ??

Comment: So as soon as you close your connection, your temporary table will be dropped, what exactly is the problem you are trying to resolve here?

Comment: I couldn't succeeded in finding that temporary table. so created temporary table using **Data Table** only.